# Running 2 threads and Displaying Best Result

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, jframe

I'm working on a Travelling Salesman Solver, I'm trying to make it execute in two threads and return the path drawing(Jframe) and the path distance/output of the best search.

My Code is below:

```
  Executer myRunnable = new Executer();
    Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
    t.start();
    t.join();
    int tdist=(Executer.returnPathValue());
    int []comparet = returnSearchedPath();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(myRunnable);
    t1.start();
    t1.join();

    int t1dist=(Executer.returnPathValue());
    int []comparet2 = returnSearchedPath();

    if(tdist<t1dist){
        printPath(comparet);
        System.out.println(tdist);
    }
    else{
        printPath(comparet2);
        System.out.println(t1dist);
    }
```

The output from this is

```
SEARCH COMMENCING:
32 10 51 13 12 26 24 23 47 45 15 49 19 29 28 46 25 27 11 50 3 43 22 20 41 1 6 16 2 17 30 21 0 48 31 44 18 40 7 8 9 14 5 4 37 36 33 34 35 38 39 42 32->dist 8904
```

My only problem NOW is accomplishing the same result without using .join() and let the threads run at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you need to wait for both threads to complete and then compare the results and choose the one you want to display. What is it that you are having trouble with? In the code you have shown, you are displaying both paths.

Comment: How would I run the thread without displaying the result first?

Comment: How would you define "best output?"  Do you mean to add up the total path length?  Do you mean some sub-path length?  We don't know what your output represents...

Comment: Save it in a variable.

Comment: because in my run method for the threads is the code for outputting the result, when I click start it will automatically output

Comment: So... don't do that?  It only automatically outputs because you printed it.  Don't print it.

Comment: Then you need to move the code that outputs from the thread. You need to have that outside the thread so you can call it for the result of just one thread.

Comment: Made some changes can you look at my code @clinomaniac it works right now the only problem is I'm using .join to allow each thread to complete save their vars and then compare - how would I accomplish the same result running them concurrently to save time?

Comment: Do I HAVE to wait for both of them to complete basically I want to accomplish the same result I have without using .join @markspace

Comment: What you are doing doesn't use threads. You start a thread and then wait for it to finish. Might as well have function calls and wait for them to finish. You need to have something that will be able to get the results separately from the threads after execution so you don't need to wait for sequential finishing of each thread.

Comment: How would I accomplish that..?

Comment: But the result would be the result that's the final of each thread @

Comment: Take a look at [Thread Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I HAVE to wait for both of them to complete basically I want to accomplish the same result I have without using .join

I think I understand.  There are techniques where you can get output from a thread without waiting on it specifically.  The basic technique is a producer-consumer pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Here's a simple way to do this in Java.  First, make a global thread-safe queue.

```
public class Global {

  public static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue outputQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

}
```

Then pass this queue in to any thread you want.  Use this queue to save output from that thread.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

  private final Queue output;

  /** 'q' must be thread safe */
  public MyTask( Queue q ) {
    output = q;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {

    // do stuff

    int [] path = ...
    output.add( path );
  }

}
```

Now you can just read the queue to get output, or decide not to read it.  You can also dedicate one thread to output and let the main thread do other things.  (This is what is typically done in a producer-consumer problem.)  You can also produce output but not finish, and continue producing results and add them to the queue as you are able to calculate them.  This works well for progressive type problems.

This code wasn't tested, and sorry for using raw types, it's just a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are needing an ArrayList of your threads and a variable to hold the current best path. In the thread class, you need two Synchronized methods. Synchronized methods are ones that are thread-safe. This means that if you have multiple threads running you can change data in another thread safely. If you want to read more about how that works you can go to this link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html). You will need one method to update the current best route if the route the thread found is less than the current best and you will need one function to remove itself from the ArrayList in the main thread when it is finished. This means you would have a blocking while loop in the main thread that looks something like this:

```
//Where threads is the ArrayList of all of your threads
while(!threads.isempty()){
    //Wait here
}
```

Then after that while ends you can check the current best path variable and that should be the best one. Now you do not have to wait for it to break out of the while loop to update the JFrame. You can change the JFrame when the current best does not match what the current JFrame is showing inside the while loop but once you get out you should double check that the correct one is being shown. Exiting means all threads are done so the final answer would be whatever is left in the current best path.

Comment: Confusing is there not a simpler way to approach this?

Comment: EDIT: I've made some changes can you look at my code?